# Selecting data MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL database there are 2 tables:

```
Table-1:
COMMODITY_COLUMN
CommodityType1
CommodityType2
..............
CommodityType20


Table-2
RECORD_ID    COMMODITY_COLUMN       VALUE   DATE
1             CommodityType6         156     15/08/96
2             CommodityType13        56      25/12/16   
3             CommodityType5         756     15/02/05
.             CommodityType4         584
.             CommodityType13        48
.             CommodityType2         78
.             CommodityType2         8
.             CommodityType6         55
.             CommodityType14        7
.             CommodityType4         88
.             ..........................
128           CommodityType5         756     19/04/72
129           CommodityType2         999     25/04/85
```

Table-1 column "COMMODITY_COLUMN" used as foreign key in the Table-2.
What I am trying to do is to collect LAST values of each 20 CommodityTypes from the Table-2.

I have tryied different MYSQL expressions such as:

```
SELECT TABLE-2.VALUE FROM TABLE-2 WHERE COMMODITY_COLUMN IN (SELECT COMMODITY_COLUMN FROM TABLE-1) ORDER BY RECORD_ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

But I am not succeeded. I can create 20 diffetent expression for each 20 commodity codes but I do not think it is good way of programming.

Could anybody suggest please a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t2.RECORD_ID,
    t2.COMMODITY_COLUMN,
    t2.VALUE,
    t2.`DATE`
FROM
    `TABLE-2` t2
    JOIN (SELECT
            MAX(RECORD_ID) AS RECORD_ID
          FROM
            `TABLE-2`
          GROUP BY
            COMMODITY_COLUMN) AS tt2 ON t2.RECORD_ID = tt2.RECORD_ID
```

Given the query you tried, I assumed `RECORD_ID` is the auto-incremented primary key, and that by "last" you meant last row inserted for that commodity.

Just to explain what's going on: the `SELECT` statement inside the `JOIN` gets the last/max `RECORD_ID` for every `COMMODITY_COLUMN`. Then that "table" `tt2` is joined with `t2` on `RECORD_ID` to get only those rows from `t2`.

Comment: @Rat2good excellent, I'm glad I could help! You should also mark it as the answer then.

Answer (score 2):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM TABLE2 t2
WHERE t2.record_id = (SELECT MAX(tt2.record_id)
                      FROM table2 tt2
                      WHERE tt2.COMMODITY_COLUMN = t2.COMMODITY_COLUMN
                     ) ;
```

I don't think `table1` has anything to do with the query.

Comment: Tha...k y...u @Gordon Linoff, but I get foolowing message when apply you expression to my database:  `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)`

Comment: I am new SQL, could you please advise I gues "t2" and "tt2" are aliases? Is there typo at the end of the expression: `...t2.COMMODITY_COLUMNFROM);` Should it be FROM at the end of this expression?

Comment: @Rat2good . . . `t2` and `tt2` are table aliases.  There was a typo with `FROM` at the end of one of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT COMMODITY_COLUMN, VALUE, MAX(DATE) 
  FROM TABLE-2
    GROUP BY COMMODITY_COLUMN;
```

Comment: This query will get the max date, but is not guaranteed to return the corresponding `VALUE`. I don't believe SQL defines which row the `VALUE` will come from in this case - it could be any.

Comment: @Unix One Are you sure about that? can you give an example (e.g., using SQL Fiddel) where it gives _value_ which is not corresponding to the _MAX(date)_?

Comment: I'm absolutely certain - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bee62c/1/0 - to explain further, you're grouping by `COMMODITY_COLUMN` and selecting aggregate (max) of `DATE` for each of them. The database will not implicitly link that aggregate date value back to any specific row from which it will select other column values. If you wanted to identify the row from which the `MAX(DATE)` value came, you'd have to say so in SQL via a sub-select or a join, while also accounting for possibility of 2 or more rows containing the same `DATE` value, e.g. via `MAX(ID)` or whatever other rule you'd resolve that case.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's an important lesson for me.